# Windows 10, develop Android project in Qt Creator

Tags: android, windows, qt, windows-10

I would like to build my Android project in Qt Creator (Ver. 4.3.1). I've set JDK, Android SDK and NDK location in Tools -> Options -> Devices -> Android. Then Qt Creator show info: Found 8 toolchains for this NDK and a warning: Qt versions for 2 architectures are missing. To add the Qt versions, select Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions.[image: Qt Versions settings]

So I set Qt versions, and I got 2 auto-detected Qt versions. Qt 5.9.0 for Android armv7 and for Android x86. Both with warning signs. The warning is No compiler can produce code for this Qt version. Please define one or more compilers for: arm-linux-android-elf-32bit. I am using Windows 10, why the ABI is arm-linux-android-elf-32bit? And what compiler can I use? I've set MinGW and Microsoft Visual C++ compiler 14.0. Both has same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it

- downloaded `android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.zip` from https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html, Downloads -> Older versions (NDK Archives)
- extracted the contained folder to C: `(-> Folder C:\android-ndk-r10e)`
- in the Qt Creator in `Tools -> Options -> Devices -> Android` set the NDK location to `C:\android-ndk-r10e` and pressed **OK**

Now when I open Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions the auto detected compilers are valid.